# Re-render after redux dispatch

Tags: redux, state

I have a FormControlLabel component in my app, a redux action is dispatched 'onChange' and the state in the store gets updated correctly except that the component does not get updated on the screen. How do I tell react that a re-render needs to be performed after the action is dispatched?

I can leverage useState but it is redundant to use a redux store and a useState hook at the same time; I want my store to be the only state source in my app.

Comment: You need control value for you inputs/text/etc

Comment: @AlexChirkin Can you elaborate more? Maybe with an example?

Comment: FYI, it is [recommended that you don't store form state in redux](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#avoid-putting-form-state-in-redux) since `onChange` gets called so many times.  It's better to `useState` and only `dispatch` to redux when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opposite to `useDispatch` is `useSelector`. If a selected value from the state would change, your component will automatically rerender.

```js
const value = useSelector(state => state.someSlice.someValue)
```